# expected 'QueueNode ** {aka struct qNode **}' but argument is of type 'QueueNode *** {aka struct qNode ***}

Tags: c, pointers, types, queue

I'm having issues about making this queue work. The value of the queue node is a struct Appointment which has two more struct in it (patient and symptoms). I've already tried using this queue structure with a simple int value and it works just fine. What am I missing?

```
    #ifndef appointmentFunctions_H__
    #define appointmentFunctions_H__
    
    #include "signupFunctions.h"
    
    typedef struct{
        int cough;
        int rDistress;
        int fatigue;
        int fever;
    }symptoms;
    
    typedef symptoms *Symptoms;
    
    typedef struct {
        Patient patient;
        Symptoms symptoms;
        int day;
        int mon;
        int year;
        int flag;
    }appointment;
    
    typedef appointment *AppointmentPtr;
    
    typedef struct qNode{
        AppointmentPtr A;
        struct qNode *next;
    }QueueNode;
    
    typedef QueueNode *qNodePtr;
    
    void printQueue(qNodePtr currentPtr);
    int isEmpty(qNodePtr head);
    void dequeue(qNodePtr *head, qNodePtr *tail);
    void enqueue(qNodePtr *head, qNodePtr *tail, AppointmentPtr App);

int isEmpty(qNodePtr head){
    return head == NULL;
}

void enqueue(qNodePtr *head, qNodePtr *tail, AppointmentPtr App){
    qNodePtr nPtr;

    nPtr = malloc(sizeof(QueueNode));

    if(nPtr != NULL){
        nPtr -> A = App;
        nPtr -> next = NULL;

        if( isEmpty(*head) ){
            *head = nPtr;
        }
        else {
            ( *tail )->next = nPtr;
        }
        *tail = nPtr;
    }
    else{
        printf("Memory unavailable.");
    }
}

void dequeue(qNodePtr *head, qNodePtr *tail){
    qNodePtr tmp;

    tmp = *head;
    *head = (*head)->next;

    if(*head == NULL){
        *tail = NULL;
    }

    free(tmp);
}
```

Those are the errors:

```
appointmentFunctions.c: In function 'requestAppointment':
appointmentFunctions.c:96:21: warning: passing argument 1 of 'enqueue' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             enqueue(&head,&tail,A);
                     ^
In file included from appointmentFunctions.c:6:0:
appointmentFunctions.h:36:6: note: expected 'QueueNode ** {aka struct qNode **}' but argument is of type 'QueueNode *** {aka struct qNode ***}'
 void enqueue(qNodePtr *head, qNodePtr *tail, AppointmentPtr App);
      ^~~~~~~
appointmentFunctions.c:96:27: warning: passing argument 2 of 'enqueue' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             enqueue(&head,&tail,A);
                           ^
In file included from appointmentFunctions.c:6:0:
appointmentFunctions.h:36:6: note: expected 'QueueNode ** {aka struct qNode **}' but argument is of type 'QueueNode *** {aka struct qNode ***}'
 void enqueue(qNodePtr *head, qNodePtr *tail, AppointmentPtr App);
      ^~~~~~~
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is written in the message: You passed wrong type of pointer. What you are missing is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Related, example of why hiding pointer types in typedef aliases is 10x more self-obfuscating than it is helpful. It has *two* legitimate use cases (callback function-pointer declarations and blackbox handle-apis). Neither apply here. Embrace your inner C engineer: see the splats.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the `requestAppointment` function that you have not shown.